# df.apply( ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to create a pd.DataFrame with 2 columns 'JV', 'Tags' basis a dictionary self.tags but getting following exception

```
tgs = {'JV':list(self.tags.keys())}
tagsData = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tgs)
tagsData['Tags'] = tagsData.apply(lambda row: self.tags[row['JV']], axis = 1)
```

dictionary example

```
self.tags = { 40: "Test"}
```

Exception in Tkinter callback

> Traceback (most recent call last): ValueError: Cannot set a frame with
>   no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Comment: Can you give an example of the dictionary  you are referring to?

Comment: edited my question above to give you an example of dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

received this error when the dictionary was empty and so could not create a dataframe from empty dictionary.

So the solution is to check for empty dictionary and act accordingly